# passing function to a decorator in cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

How do I pass the `index()` to the decorator function called `uppercase()`. I want the value passed from `index()` to be capitalized.

I am getting this error:

```
500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 638, in respond
    self._do_respond(path_info)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 701, in _do_respond
    self.hooks.run('before_finalize')
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 95, in run
    self.run_hooks(iter(sorted(self[point])))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 117, in run_hooks
    hook()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 65, in __call__
    return self.callback(**self.kwargs)
TypeError: uppercase() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

---

```py
import cherrypy
from cherrypy import tools

@cherrypy.tools.register('before_finalize')
def uppercase(func):
    def wrapper():
        original_result = func()
        modified_result = original_result.upper()
        return modified_result
    return wrapper

class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.uppercase()
    def index(self):
        return 'Hello!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.tools.uppercase = cherrypy.Tool('before_finalize', uppercase)
    cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: Remove the `()` from `@cherrypy.tools.uppercase()`, A decorator is called implicitly with the function it is decorating as the first argument. You're calling it explicitly with no argument, which is why you're see the error "missing 1 required positional argument".

Comment: TypeError: The 'uppercase' Tool does not accept positional arguments; you must use keyword arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the decorator like this:

```
@cherrypy.tools.uppercase
def index(self):
    return 'Hello!'
```

Note the lack of `()` after `uppercase` - a decorator takes the first argument (the decorated function) implicitly and the parentheses are not needed.

Edit:

According to [the documentation](https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/extend.html#tools), a tool can be defined using the `cherrypy.tools.register` decorator, or the `cherrypy.Tool` constructor. In your code, you define the `uppercase` tool twice.

But, in your case the `uppercase` decorator does not need to be defined as a `Tool`, because it's not something that needs to be ran every time as a hook (before_finalize).

Therefore, you will be better off with just using it as a plain Python decorator, like so:

```
from functools import wraps

# just a plain Python decorator
def uppercase(func):
    @wraps(func) #preserve function attributes, such as its name
    def wrapper(*args):
        original_result = func(*args)
        modified_result = original_result.upper()
        return modified_result
    return wrapper

class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    @uppercase # decorated once, the exposed function is now uppercase(index) 
    def index(self):
        return 'Hello!'
```

Comment: I tried but I get this error
TypeError: The 'uppercase' Tool does not accept positional arguments; you must use keyword arguments.

Comment: @jeril I updated the answer, check if this approach helps.

Comment: Nope..tried with plain python decorator.. TypeError: wrapper() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @jeril Of course, my bad, the wrapper assumes that the decorated function takes no arguments, but it does take “self”. You can add *args to the definition of the wrapper and to the call of func inside.